# Getting error syntax error: unexpected "("When building a C program in Docker

Tags: c, docker, gcc

I am trying to build a C program inside a Docker container, I just would like to create a binary file and execute it in the container. I receive no error during compilation but
when running within my container the binary file created on Linux Alpine I get this error message:

```
/usr/jjj-app/bin # ./jjj-linux.out 
./jjj-linux.out: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
/usr/jjj-app/bin #
```

Notes: I am running `make build-linux` from the host, in my case macOS.

Any ideas how to build this simple program in Linux environment using Docker? I can use Alpine or another.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
build-linux:
    docker build -t jjj-app .
    docker run --publish 8081:8080 jjj-app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add build-base
COPY . /usr/jjj-app
WORKDIR /usr/jjj-app
RUN gcc /usr/jjj-app/src/main.c -o /usr/jjj-app/bin/jjj-linux.out -r
```

Comment: could be related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214003/first-c-program-hello-world-keep-getting-syntax-error ?

Comment: what's the "-r" for? that's partial linking, you need to finish linking it, before you execute it

Comment: What does `file ./jjj-linux.out` say? (If you had actually compiled your C program, it would say it was an ELF executable; the error implies that it isn't actually a binary at all, and is being interpreted as a shell script instead).

Comment: removing -r solved it many thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gcc `-r` flag is for partial linking. Presumably to do whole program optimization or other linker steps later on.

If you want a finished exectuable you need to finish linking it.

Either by running gcc again `gcc /usr/jjj-app/bin/jjj-linux.out -o /usr/jjj-app/bin/jjj-linux.done.out`

or just removing the `-r`